# Einstein field equations for infinite cylinder

Tags: general-relativity

What does the exterior metric look like for an infinitely long cylindrical mass distribution? I'm assuming the stress energy tensor, $T_{\mu\nu}=0$ outside the cylinder and that the cylinder has no angular momentum.

Comment: A mass distribution can’t have a zero energy-momentum tensor. Do you mean zero *outside the cylinder*?

Comment: @G.Smith Yes, sorry. I was in a rush when I made this post.

Comment: I don't think this is enough information to specify  the problem. Even the analogous problem for a sphere is not straightforward and requires for self-consistency that you set up some kind of equation of state that allows the sphere to be in hydrodynamic equilibrium.

Comment: @BenCrowell I'm not sure what you mean. You can assume the simplest case, for example, that the mass is uniformly distributed within the cylinder.

Comment: The axisymmetric metric in the static case is investigated by Weil and Levy-Chevita. In the case of gravitational waves, the problem was studied by Rosen and Einstein. What is your case?

Comment: @RyanParikh: *You can assume the simplest case, for example, that the mass is uniformly distributed within the cylinder.* GR is not Newtonian gravity. You can't have a self-consistent, static solution to the field equations if there is nothing to keep the mass from collapsing. This contributes to the stress-energy. However, you may be OK if all you want is the exterior field.

Comment: Have a look at https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.06561.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most general static vacuum solution of Einstein equations with a cylindrical symmetry is the *Levi–Civita metric*:
$$ds^2=r^{8σ^2−4σ}(dr^2+dz^2) +D^2r^{2−4σ}dφ^2−r^{4σ}dt^2$$
where $σ$ and $D$ are constants and the coordinate $φ$ is assumed to be periodic with a period of $2\pi$ (if we drop periodicity requirement the solution could be interpreted as a metric outside of infinite wall). The metric generally has curvature singularity at $r=0$ and is flat in the limit $r\to \infty$.

More on this metric including possible sources for it could be found in [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9512029) or [that](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9607058) papers.

Comment: I was trying to get the equations for an infinite cylinder, like how you can use Gauss' law to find the gravitational field outside an infinitely long cylinder in classical physics. In those cases the math simplifies and it can be used as an approximation for a finite cylinder. I plugged it into the Einstein Field Equations and ended up with imaginary numbers that I couldn't get rid of. I assume this means there is no solution for this in general relativity, you can only find the metric for finitely long cylinders. It is also possible that I made an error in the math.

Comment: @RyanParikh: I do not know what constraints you are trying to impose, so I could not comment on “imaginary numbers” problem, but there are perfect fluid sources for LC metric, see e.g. Haggag & Desokey, 1996, https://dx.doi.org/10.1088/0264-9381/13/12/012

Comment: The issue is that I was trying to get a metric that is asymptotically flat. The field equations don't have a solution like that with cylindrical symmetry. I guess this can be seen as a feature of general relativity.

Comment: @RyanParikh: Nontrivial solution with cylindrical symmetry  means that there is finite curvature (and also sources of stress–energy, etc) at arbitrarily large distances from the origin. This would directly contradict with “asymptotically flat” assumption.